# Difference between sampling rate, bit rate and bit depth

Tags: audio, sampling, bitrate, bit-depth

This is kind of a *basic* question which *might* sound too obvious to many of you , but I am **getting confused** so bad.

Here is what a [Quora user says](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-Sampling-rate-Bit-depth-and-Bit-rate-related-to-MP3-files-and-how-do-they-affect-the-quality-of-the-output-sound). Now It is clear to me what a Sampling rate is -  The number of samples you take of a sound signal (in one second) is it's sampling rate.

Now my doubt here is - This rate should have nothing to do with the *quantisation*, right?

About **bit-depth**, Is the quantisation dependant on bit-depth? As in 32-bit (2^32 levels) and 64-bit (2^64 levels). Or is it something else?

and the bit-rate, is number of bits *transferred* in one second? If I an audio file says 320 kbps what does that really mean?

I assume the readers have got some sense on how I am panicking on where does the **bit rate**, and **bit depth** have significance?

**EDIT:** Also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54669358/resample-and-depayload-audio-rtp-using-gstreamer) if you have worked with linux OS and gstreamer framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my doubt here is - This rate should have nothing to do with the
>   quantisation, right?

Wrong. Sampling is a process that results in quantisation. Sampling, as the name implies, means taking samples (amplitudes) of a (usually) continuous signal (e.g audio) at regular time intervals and converting them to a different represantation thereof. In digital signal processing, this represantation is discrete (not continuous). An example of this process is a `wave` file (e.g recording your own voice and saving it as a wav).

> About bit-depth, Is the quantisation dependant on bit-depth? As in
>   32-bit (2^32 levels) and 64-bit (2^64 levels). Or is it something
>   else?

Yes. The CD format, for example, has a bit depth of 16 (16 bits per sample). Bit depth is a part of the format of a sound (wave) file (along with the number of channels and sampling rate).
Since  sound (think of a pure sine tone)  has both  positive and negative parts, I'd argue that you can represent  (2^16 / 2) amplitude levels using 16 bits.

> and the bit-rate, is number of bits transferred in one second? If I an
>   audio file says 320 kbps what does that really mean?

Yes. Bit rates are usually meaningful in the context of network transfers. `320 kbps` == 320 000 bits per second. (for kilobit you multiply by 1000, rather than 1024)

Comment: `I'd argue that you can represent (2^16 / 2) amplitude levels using 16 bits` These _amplitude levels_ you are refering to `taking samples (amplitudes)`?

Comment: `you can represent (2^16 / 2) amplitude levels using 16 bits` Why won't I take a bigger number then? say 64. What limits me? My OS? (example Opensuse 32 bit OS)

Comment: @RC0993, No, there's simply no need for that. Some audio uses even 24 bits but 16 bits is enough to encode sound dynamics. Using 64 bits would unnecessarily waste memory. Note that programs may use more bits (e.g 32 bit float) but that's usually because it's easier to process wave files in memory using floats (range -1 + 1), especially if you're manipulating sound in any way.

Comment: Okay! Now `bit-rate, is number of bits transferred in one second` transferred to where?

Comment: E.g from the server to your computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188351/discussion-between-rc0993-and-dsp-user).

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a worked example ['Red-book' CD audio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Disc_Digital_Audio)

- The *Bit depth* is 16-bit. This is the number of bits used to represent each sample. This is intimately coupled with quantisation.
- The *Smaple-rate* is 44.1kHz
- The *Frame-rate* is 44.1kHz (two audio channels make up a stereo pair)
- The *Bit-rate* is therefore `16 * 44100 * 2 = 1411200` bits/sec

There are a few twists with compressed audio streams such such as MP3 or AAC. In these, there is a non-linear relationship between bit-rate, sample-rate and bit-depth. The bit-rate is generally the maximum rate per-second and the efficiency of the codec is content dependant.

Comment: Thanks for the example. The significance and limitations are still not clear :(