# Resample and depayload audio rtp using gstreamer

Tags: c++, audio, gstreamer, pipeline, resampling

I am developing an application where I am using a ***wave file*** from a location at one end of a pipeline and ***udpsink*** at the other end of it.

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/path/to/wave/file/Tornado.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,depth=16,width=16,rate=44100 ! rtpL16pay  ! udpsink host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port=5000
```

The Above wave file is having sampling rate = 44100 Hz and single-channel(mono)

On the same PC I am using a `c++` program application to **catch these packets** and **depayload** to a headerless audio file *(say Tornado.raw)*

The pipeline I am creating for this is basically

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)44100, width=16, height=16, encoding-name=(string)L16, encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(int)1, payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay ! filesink location=Tornado.raw
```

Now This works fine. I get the headerless data and when I play it using the Audacity It plays great!

I am trying to resample this audio file while it is in pipeline from 44100 Hz to 8000 Hz

Simply changing the `clock-rate=(int)44100` to `clock-rate=(int)8000` is not helping (also absurd logically)
I am looking for how to get the headerless file at the pipeline output  with 8000 Hz sampling.

Also the data that I am getting now is Big-endian, but I want Little-endian as output. how do I set that in the pipeline?

You might relate this to one of [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664381/difference-between-sampling-rate-bit-rate-and-bit-depth).

Comment: Resampling from `44100` to `8000` Hz will result in `44100/8000` times fewer samples (rounded to an integer) but you first need to pass your signal (or parts of it) through a low pass filter to remove the high frequency component (otherwise you'll get aliasing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have some weird caps in your pipeline - width and height are for video here. They probably will be just ignored.. but still.. not sure on others there as well but meh..

For the actual question. Just use `audioresample` and `audioconvert` elements of Gstreamer to transfer in your desired format.

E.g.

```
[..] ! rtpL16depay ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! \
audio/x-raw, rate=8000, format=S16LE ! filesink location=Tornado.raw
```